# Showing data from related tables in single datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have some tables in the db:

```
Items             Manufacturers       Categories      Cities      Regions
==============    ================    ============    ========    ==========
ItemId            ManufacturerId      CategoryId      CityId      RegionId
ManufacturerId    CityId              NameCategory    RegionId    NameRegion
CategoryId        NameManufacturer                    NameCity
NameItem
Weight
```

I am displaying the list of the items in `DataGridView` using this code:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Items", connectionString);

SqlCommandBuilder cmdBldr = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
da.Fill(ds, "Items");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

I also have  button that save the changes in the `DataGridView` with this code:

```
da.Update(ds, "Items");
```

I want to replace two columns in datagridview - `ManufacturerId` and `CategoryId` with the `NameManufacturer` and `NameCategory` from related tables. So those two columns should be ComboBox with all possible names from related tables - to be able to change the `Category` or `Manufacturer` to other and save it using da.Update().

I also need to add three combobox filters for the datagridview:
`Category`, `City` and `Region`, that will filter the displayed items in the datagridview by selected values in those filters.

I can't use wizard creator, I have to do it all in the code.
If you could give me some ideas related to any part of this, will be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ComboBox Column

For each column that you want to be combo box, you should create an instance of [`DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) and set these properties and add it to `Columns` of grid:

- `DataSource`: list of items that you want to show in combo box
- `DataPropertyName`: Name of a property of data source of grid, that you want to combobox bind to it.
- `DisplayMember`: Name of a column of data source of combo box to show in combo box
- `ValueMember`: Name of a column of data source of combo box to use its value when you select an item from combo box.

For example here is the code for `CategoryId` column:

```
var categoryAdapter= new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Categories", connectionString);
var categoryTable= new DataTable();
categoryAdapter.Fill(categoryTable);

var categoryComboBoxColumn=new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
categoryComboBoxColumn.Name="categoryComboBoxColumn";
categoryComboBoxColumn.HeaderText="Category";
categoryComboBoxColumn.DataSource = categoryTable;
categoryComboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "CategoryId";
categoryComboBoxColumn.DisplayMember= "NameCategory";
categoryComboBoxColumn.DisplayMember= "CategoryId";
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(categoryComboBoxColumn);
```

### Filter

To filter the grid you can assign an [expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) to `DefaultView.RowFilter` of your main data table.

For example to filter based on `CategoryId`, you can create a `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox` control and name it for example `categoryComboBox` and bind it to categories to show list of categories and set its `DisplayMember` to `NameCategory` and its `ValueMember` to `CategoryId` in that combo box and then:

```
var table = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);
table.DefaultView.RowFilter = 
    string.Format("CategoryId = {0}", categoryComboBox.SelectedValue);
```

You can reset the filter by setting it to null or empty.

Also you can create expression with and / or:

```
var criterias = new List<string>();
if(categoryComboBox.SelectedIndex > 0)
    criterias.Add(string.Format("CategoryId = {0}", categoryComboBox.SelectedValue);

if(cityComboBox.SelectedIndex > 0)
    criterias.Add(string.Format("CityId = {0}", cityComboBox.SelectedValue);

var table = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);
table.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Join(" And " , criterias);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it helps me a lot! I just have question about filtering by city or region. In this case in the default view table - i mean items table from gridview - there is no CityId, or RegionId. Those values are in parent table of items - Manufacturer for example. How to reach there?

Comment: I think the most simple way is load your data with a join to those tables to contain `RegionId` and `CityId`. Another way could be using the relation, you can read more about `Parent/Child Relation Referencing` in [expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I recommend using the join solution. If you tried and need more help, let me know :) By the way, it's better to ask only one question in a post and if you need more help with filter in the specific case,  I think it's better to ask a new question :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Let me know what did you do with filter?

Comment: I tested the solution with the Join, is working :) but becouse i'm learning possibilities, i also try with the relations. I created relations between the tables in dataset. For the City filter in the RowFilter i simply use "Parent.CityId" and it's working correctly. But for the region filter i have a problem. i can't use Parent.Parent.RegionId, becouse it throw error. What should i put in the RowFilter to call to the 2nd level parent?

Comment: I think you can use a workaround for that `Parent.Parent.RegionId`

Comment: Add a calculated field to your `Manufacturers` data table and set the expression of it to `Parent.RegionId` and name the column `RegionId` then you can simply use `Parent.RegionId` in filter

Comment: By theway, While you can mark only  one answer as accepted, but you can kindly vote up as many answers you find helpful, including the accepted one by click on up arrow near the answer :)